# Assembly to C - (variable stored on ebp rather than esp)

Tags: assembly

I've a problem interpreting the following piece of code. I think 8 and 5 should be members of an array. But if I define an array, they are stored on ebp-something rather than esp. I know that variables are stored on esp if a function is called, but there is no..

```
main:
  pushl %ebp
  ....
  movl $8, 28(%esp)
  movl $5, 32(%esp)
  movl 28(%esp), %eax
  movl %eax, t
  movl $0, 36(%esp)
  jmp .L1
```

what I got:

```
int t;

int main()
{

int array[] = {9, 4, 0, 5, 1, -4, -6, 7};
t = array[0];

return 0;
}

movl    $8, -8(%ebp)
movl    $5, -4(%ebp)
movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
movl    %eax, t
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in using a specific register. Both `ebp` and `esp` can be used to address stack positions; moreover, any other register is possible (but not in traditions) in a flat-memory (not segmented) 32-bit application. The main issue is that

- In 16-bit code, one can't use `sp` for direct stack addressing. `bp` was intended for this. That required prologue (`push bp`, `mov bp,sp`) and epilogue. Moreover, this style is handy for a human because `bp` is fixed for a function invocation so offsets doesn't change.
- In 32-bit code (and in 64-bit code, with `rsp`, `rbp` instead of `esp`, `ebp`), addressing using stack pointer has been added. This allows compiler to avoid prologue and epilogue creating. The drawback is that offsets of the same stack cell upon `esp` are changed each time anything is pushed or popped. Compilers deal with this easier than a human.

In your example, you've missed principal part. In think, in generated code, `esp` was decremented by 36 immediately after pushing `ebp`. That's why `-8(%ebp)` is the same address as `28(%esp)`. You can force keeping framing-support code in functions but not using only `ebp` for stack addressing, if GCC prefers `esp` for this.

Comment: So, can I force GCC to use esp with a specific c-code?

Comment: AFAIK you can't. The available options are whether to create stack frame in `ebp` register but not the specific stack access style.